# В чем разница функционального выражения и объявления функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

Например есть обычное объявление функции:

```
var someFunction = function() {
    ...
};
```

И функциональое выражение:

```
function someFunction() {
    ...
}
```

В чем принципиальная разница?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разница в том, что обычная функция `function declaration` создается интерпретатором до начала выполнения кода.

### Пример `Declaration Function`:

```js
someFunction("Hello world!");

function someFunction(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

Как видно из примера, объявления функции стоит после ее вызова и код работает корректно.

### Пример `Function Expression` (функциональное выражение):

Функциональное выражение создается интерпретатором во время выполнения кода, то есть синхронно, от строки к строке. И в таком случае вызов функции до ее инициализации приведет к ошибке, потому что функция еще не создана, а вы ее уже вызываете.

```js
someFunction("Hello world!");

var someFunction = function(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

### use strict

Еще один момент, если вы используете директиву `use strict`, то обычное объявление функции не даст вам вызывать функцию вне тела блока в котором она инициализирована, например в условии.

```js
'use strict'

if (1 > 0) {
  function someFunction(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
}

someFunction("Hello world!");
```

Функциональное выражение же сработает в этом случае, если переменная инициализирована в теле блока или 'выше', в котором она будет использоваться.

```js
'use strict'

let someFunction;

if (1 > 0) {
  someFunction = function(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
}

someFunction("Hello world!");
```